# Подстрока bytes строки в виде bytes строки

Tags: python, байты

Как получить подстроку `bytes` объекта в виде `bytes` объекта?

```
b'\x02\x03'
```

Хочу получить подстроку с 0 по 1 байт

```
b'\x02'
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = b'\x02\x03'

print(a[0:1]) #=> b'\x02'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
b'\x02\x03'.decode()[0].encode()
```